# bcrypt module is not working in asynchronously

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, bcrypt

I am trying to do a user login and sign up page, the bycrpt module works while in the signup process to hash the password asynchronously but while trying to use in login code the await is not begin applied to it, can I know why?

```
try{
    
    await bcrypt.compare(password,user.password,(err,result)=>{
        if(result){
            res.send('done')
        }
        else{
            res.send('nope')
        }
    })
   }
   catch(err){
    console.log(err)
   }
```

`It says await has no effect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It already works with a `callback`. That way it will not return you a `Promise`. You can continue your transactions in the callback.

If you still want it to return `Promise`, you can try as follows:

```js
    const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
    
    (async () => {
        try {
            const result = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    
            if (result) {
                console.log('done');
            } else {
                console.log('nope');
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })()
```